# python format take the real length for fabric colored strings

Tags: python, colors, terminal, fabric

I use python fabric to colorize terminal output, and String formatting to align text.

Colors add invisible code to string, how do I not break the formatting output?

```
>>> from fabric.colors import red
>>> print '{:->27}'.format('line one')
-------------------line one
>>> print '{:->27}'.format('longer line two')
------------longer line two
>>> print '{:->27}'.format(red('line three'))
--------line three
>>>
```

As Hans said, we just have to add +9

```
>>> 
>>> print '{:->27}'.format('line one')
-------------------line one
>>> print '{:->27}'.format('longer line two')
------------longer line two
>>> print '{:->36}'.format(red('line three'))
-----------------line three
>>> print '{:->36}'.format(red('and more words'))
-------------and more words
>>> print '{:->36}'.format(red('and more words plus one'))
----and more words plus one
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [source code](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/colors.py) of fabric for colors contains this:

```
def _wrap_with(code):
    def inner(text, bold=False):
        c = code
        if bold:
            c = "1;%s" % c
        return "\033[%sm%s\033[0m" % (c, text)
    return inner

red = _wrap_with('31')
```

And your 'line three' outputs a line 9 characters shorter than the others,
I guess the output of red(*String*) always contains 9 invisible characters, stored by the string "\033[%sm%s\033[0m".

So to fix your formatting, when using red(*String*), you should type

```
print '{:->(27+9)}'.format(red('line three'))
```

instead of

```
print '{:->27}'.format(red('line three'))
```